# ReSubmit app that Remove from sale

Tags: ios

My IOS app live on market but some problem to remove from appstore so how can i will resubmit app on appstore

any other solution to resubmit and live again my IOS app

Comment: Have you deleted your app from iTunes account?

Answer (score 1):

1. Resolve all issues, then upload a new version.
2. Add new version of live app.
3. More help at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html).

Comment: so where is the link?